# Taking specific data with given index in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I work on Visual Studio about Python project.

Here my data:

```
.......0 Hi
.......1 Guys
.....10. I am
.....00. Asel
```

So, I want to read that text file line by line and find if the `7th` of index is `0` then print `Hi` or `1` print `Guys`. Moreover, if `5th` and `6th` indexes are `1` and `0` print `I am` otherwise if they are `0` and `0` print `Asel`.

Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Have you write any code for ding this?

Comment: isn't this simply if and elifs?

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work ?

Answer (score 2):

Open the file, read line by line and test:

```
with open("foo.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line[7] == '0':
            print("Hi")
        elif....
```

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this

```
with open("path/to/file.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines :
        if line[7] == '0':
            print("Hi")
        elif line[7] == '1':
            print("guys")
        # use the else if as per the conditions
```

Comment: Actually, the text file lines so much that's why, I don't want to use if else because of the code takes so long, is there any shortest way?

Comment: unrelated but `lines = f.readlines()` will read the whole file in memory (and crash the system). Iterate over the file instead, ie `for line in f:`

Answer (score -1):

If you want something more general you can try:

```
with open('f.txt') as f:
    d={}
    lines=f.readlines()
    for line in lines[0:4]:
         line=line.replace('.','')
         ind=line.split(' ')[0]
         word=line[line.index(' ')+1:]
         d[ind]=word
    line_7_ind=lines[7].replace('.','').split(' ')[0]
    print d[line_7_ind]
```

(I assumed line 7 has `.......` too, if it doesn't use `line_7_ind=lines[7]` instead the line before the last one)